# How to execute JavaScript in Ruby written Webdriver test?

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, webdriver

Is there a known solution to perform Eval (Javascript execution) in Webdriver, Ruby bindings?

The equivalent of the following example in Java.

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id( "foo" ));
 String name = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
 "return arguments[0].tagName" , element)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The equivalent Ruby would be:

```
 name = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].tagName" , element)
```

(to get the tag name you could also just call element.tag_name)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for posting this answer. It helped me a lot. I was googling the whole day to figure out how to execute JavaScript code within Ruby.

`@driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element )`

By doing so, I was able to scroll into the specific element before click event. This might help others a bit.

I had to use JavaScript alternative because for some reason this wasn't: working for me `element.location_once_scrolled_into_view`

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do, thanks! 
I've extended my `Selenium::WebDriver::Element` to include this on elements, but I couldn't find a way to access the driver w/o passing it in as a required parameter.