# How to find a css element on the page if it is display: none?

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing, rspec

I'm running automated testing in Ruby.

I'm trying to write a script that finds id with `display:none` (visible only in mobile form), and clicks it.

Here is my code:

```
def open_menu
   page.find[:css, "a[id='mobile-nav-link']", visible: false].click
end
```

It gives me an error:

```
   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError:
   invalid selector: No selector specified
```

Comment: Are you using Capybara? Are you sure square brackets are correct? A quick search reveals similar code using round brackets, not square. I.e., `page.find(:css, "a[id='mobile-nav-link']", visible: false).click`

Comment: Thank you! It was that simple!

Comment: Great, glad that helped! I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search reveals similar code using round brackets, not square. I.e.:

```
def open_menu
   page.find(:css, "a[id='mobile-nav-link']", visible: false).click
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium only interacts with elements the way a user would.

If the link is only visible in mobile, I would suggest one of the following.

1. View the page via the mobile URL.
2. It's possible that you may be able to use Ruby's javascript execute to either update the control to be visible, or set the value that indicates you are viewing the page via a mobile device.

**Updating the control to be visible**

This link discusses how to set an element to visible using javascript execute: [Selenium Webdriver - click on hidden elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363038/selenium-webdriver-click-on-hidden-elements)

This link discusses how to use ruby's javascript execute: [How to execute Javascript in Ruby written Webdriver test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565562/how-to-execute-javascript-in-ruby-written-webdriver-test)

Put the two together, and you get something like this?

```
def open_menu
    elem = page.find[:css, "a[id='mobile-nav-link']", visible: false]
    js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto' arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';"
    driver.execute_script(js , elem)
    page.find[:css, "a[id='mobile-nav-link']", visible: true].click
end
```

I'm not entirely familiar with Ruby syntax, so I make no guarantees it will work copy/paste.

Comment: it fails on page.find .Gives me an error: 'Failure/Error: elem = page.find[:css, "a[id='mobile-nav-link']", visible: false]
     
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError:
       invalid selector: No selector specified'